# Why Java SHA1 does not Initial Vector?

Tags: java, security

I am trying to use java in built method (MessageDigest) to implement SHA1. However, in examples I have not find any method parameters to declare Initial Vector. Can anybody help me about this ???? Thanks in advance......

Comment: Are you trying to implement SHA-1 yourself? Do you really have to, since the ability to perform a SHA-1 hash is built into Java? Unless this is for an assignment, rolling your own implementation of a hash algorithm is a bad idea if there are already tried and tested implementations available.

Comment: Initial vector of what? You use the update() method to supply data to you MessageDigest instance. Can you post you code samples please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am in no way an expert in cryptography, but logically thinking, what woud IV be needed for in digest?
The point of digest is to produce seemingly random result for each input message but, as with any other hash, it must be the same for the same input. IV on the other hand are used to modify encryption algorithm to have different results for the same input.

So, I don't think there would be any IV.

Comment: Correct - message digests do not use initialization vectors.  IVs are used during encryption to make sure that a single value encrypted multiple times with the same key does not result in the same ciphertext.  The hash equivalent is a salt.

Comment: @atk I think, salt is part of PBE rather than digest definition. I don't see any reference to salt in SHA1 RFC here: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3174.html But again, I am not an expert in the field.

Comment: Alex, sorry, I guess I was unclear.  I did not intend to imply that the salt is not part of the hash algorithm, but rather additional data that is passed through the hash.